# How do I have my MacBook Pro do Auto signature in my reply email

Tags: email, signature

I can see how to have the email add a signature in replies,  but how do I set it up to be there automatically.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. It would help us if you provided additional info, such as the types of devices, OS, etc.  Also let us know what you've already done to solve the problem yourself.  Please see [ask] for how to ask good questions that have a better chance at being answered. - From Review

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). As for your question, in addition to what fsb has asked, it'd be good to confirm what email client you're using (as we can't assume you're using the default Mail app).